A variant of the law of total probability
Let $X$ be a random variable. An identity I came across is the following: $$\mathbb{P}[A\mid B] = \mathbb{E}_X[\mathbb{P}[A\mid B, X=x]$$
It appears to me something like a law of total probability so I believe it to be true but I wasn't quite able to prove it. In particular,
$$ \mathbb{E}_X[\mathbb{P}[A\mid B, X=x] = \sum_x \mathbb{P}[X=x]\mathbb{P}[A\mid B, X=x] = \sum_x \mathbb{P}[X=x]\frac{\mathbb{P}[A, B, X=x]}{\mathbb{P}[B, X=x]}$$
Looking at the summand, we have
$$ \mathbb{P}[X=x]\frac{\mathbb{P}[A, X=x, B]}{\mathbb{P}[X=x, B]} = \mathbb{P}[X=x]\frac{\mathbb{P}[A, X=x\mid B]\mathbb{P}[B]}{\mathbb{P}[X=x, B]}$$
If the events $\{X=x\}$ and $B$ are independent, then we can just use the law of total probability. However, in the context that I found this inequality, the event $B$ depends on the value that $X$ takes so it's not clear to me how to procede from here.

You are right that what you stated requires independence. The identity should be $\mathbb{P}\left[A|B\right]=\mathbb{E}_{X|B}\left[\mathbb{P}(A|B,X=x)\right]$.
Here is a counterexample to the original claim. Suppose we have nine balls. One is of type $X\&A\& B$, three are of type $\neg X\&\neg A\& B$, two are of type $X\&A\&\neg B$, and three are of type $\neg X\&\neg A\&\neg B$. A ball is drawn at random.
Then, $\mathbb{P}(A|B)=\frac{1}{4}$.
However, $\mathbb{E}_{X}\left[\mathbb{P}(A|B,X=x)\right]=\mathbb{P}(X)\mathbb{P}(A|B,X)+\mathbb{P}(\neg X)\mathbb{P}(A|B,\neg X)=\frac{3}{9}\cdot 1 + \frac{6}{9}\cdot 0=\frac{1}{3}$.

You should keep the condition $A|B$:
$$\sum_x \mathbb{P}[X=x]\mathbb{P}[A\mid B, X=x] = \sum_x \mathbb{P}[X=x]\frac{\mathbb{P}[A, X=x| B]}{\mathbb{P}[ X=x]}= \mathbb{P}[A\mid B]$$

How did you get the first equality? It seems to me you are assuming that B and ${X=x}$ are independent.
